# How to rewrite cdata elaments

Tags: xml, xslt, cdata

I have a problem with transform xml to SOAP format.
I want rewrite cdata from all xml elements.

Input XML:

```
<some>
  <A><![CDATA[2]]></A>
  <B><![CDATA[test]]></B>
  <C><![CDATA[false]]></C>
  <D><![CDATA[test]]></D>
  <E><![CDATA[3]]></E>
  <F><![CDATA[4]]></F>
  <G><![CDATA[false]]></G>
  <H><![CDATA[3]]></H>
  ...
</some>
```

I need this SOAP output :

```
<soapenv:Envelope>
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <AA><![CDATA[2]]></AA>
    <BB><![CDATA[test]]></BB>
    <oo>mydata</oo>
    <CC><![CDATA[false]]></CC>
    <pp>mydata</pp>
    <DD><![CDATA[test]]></DD>
    <rr>mydata</rr>
    <EE><![CDATA[3]]></EE>
    <FF><![CDATA[4]]></FF>
    <GG><![CDATA[false]]></GG>
    <HH><![CDATA[3]]></HH>
    ...
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

PS. 
adding cdata-section-elements  is bed solution in my example.

Comment: You can't have elements named `11` or `22` in XML, an element name can't start with a digit.

Comment: ok a corrected it.  How Can I resolved above ?

Comment: Can you explain the criteria for inserting the new elements like `<oo>mydata</oo>` or `<pp>mydata</pp>`? Where/when are they to be inserted?

Comment: I put some example nodes. Have not criteria. Maybe I shouldn't put this data , but I want not understand me. I want not prompt like "copy-of" etc.